# Parsley JS multiple step form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, parsley.js

Here is my `CoffeeScript`

```
  wizard = $('#registrationWizard').wizard()
  $form = $('.finalize-form')

  $form.parsley
    inputs: 'input, select'
    excluded: 'input[type="hidden"]'

  wizard.on 'change', (e, data) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    p = $form.parsley 'validate'

    if p
      $('#registrationWizard').wizard 'next'
  .on 'finished', (e) ->
    if $form.parsley 'isValid'
      $form.submit()
```

When the `change` event is fired on the wizard, `parsley` is trying to validate the whole form instead of just the visible inputs that are in the current step

Answer (score 1):

I believe they have what you are looking for in the [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#javascript) as an example. First you need to set up a listener to let it know you are only looking for visible inputs:

```
$( '#form' ).parsley( 'addListener', {
  onFieldValidate: function ( elem ) {

      // if field is not visible, do not apply Parsley validation!
      if ( !$( elem ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
         return true;
     }

      return false;
   }
} );
```

Then as you move through the steps in the wizard, you can validate the visible elements by simply firing off:

```
$( '#form' ).parsley( 'validate' )
```

(I apologize for the lack of coffeescript)

Answer (score 0):

If your entire form is loaded in the DOM, and you are able to use the parsely API, you can run multiple validations, one for each step of your wizard. To do that you must use the parsley-bind attribute. Something like:

```
<form action="#">

    <!-- wizard step 1 --> 
    <div class='step1' parsley-validate parsley-bind>
       <input type="text" ..... />
       <input type="text" ..... />
    </div>

    <!-- wizard step 2 --> 
    <div class='step2' parsley-validate parsley-bind>
       <input type="text" ..... />
       <input type="text" ..... />
    </div>

    <!-- wizard step 3 --> 
    <div class='step1' parsley-validate parsley-bind>
       <input type="text" ..... />
       <input type="text" ..... />
    </div>

</form>
```